# iptraf: command not found

Tags: centos

I installed iptraf on CentOS 7 to monitor the network:

```
[root@test ~]# yum install iptraf
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.osuosl.org
 * extras: mirrors.usinternet.com
 * updates: mirror.tzulo.com
Package iptraf-ng-1.1.4-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@test ~]# iptraf
bash: iptraf: command not found
```

Is this a new bug?!

Answer (score 9):

I encountered a similar problem with Ubuntu 18.04.

Just run `iptraf-ng` instead of `iptraf`.

Comment: how stupid is this?

Answer (score 5):

Your CentOS automatically decided to install `iptraf-ng` instead. The binary of the `iptraf-ng` package is `iptraf-ng`. Next time just use `rpm -ql iptraf-ng` to list the package contents.

Comment: That's not it. I had the same issue with apt, and after checking I have both iptraf and iptraf-ng. When I got the command not found error, I thought I'd forgotten to install it, so I ran the install command again. I found out not only that it was already installed, but it even gave the version, which is different from the iptraf-ng version installed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem when I tried to install `iptraf`.

I was following the instructions from [here](https://linuxhint.com/network_usage_per_process/) where it states the package to be installed is `iptraf`. On the other hand after some research I found out that `iptraf` is now actually

> a transitional dummy package to help iptraf users to upgrade to iptraf-ng, you may remove it safely

from [here](https://command-not-found.com/iptraf). So, the conclusion is:

a) that you possibly have `iptraf-ng` in your machine already and if not install this one and not the transitional dummy one (`iptraf` that is).
b) you can safely remove the dummy package without affecting the real package functionality.